# apply regex on set string that match regex

Tags: regex

I want to find out some words using regex but don't want to use words that beginning with some special character

For example
I want to select all sect in `parent.sect sect sect hello.sect sect`
but don't want to select sect `parent.sect`

Answer (score 1):

[one approach](https://regex101.com/r/iG0oP4/2) that is pretty simple is to consume (forget) the stuff you don't want first, then OR that with what you do want, which you 'remember' with `()`:

```
/parent\.sect|(sect)/g
```

Comment: it is selecting sect in parent.sect also

Comment: part of the pattern does match those, but not the () match group: check the match groups at the right.

Comment: |(sect) will select all sect incl parent.sect also

Comment: it will not, because it already tries to match the first alternative, parent.sect, at every position.

Comment: did you go to the link I provided and check your "Match Information"?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion

```pl
/(?<!parent\.)sect/
```

Comment: depends on what regex engine you use, javascript won't have lookbehinds.